# Unit testing cover catch block in RxJava Observable response

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java

I have a try-catch block in the onError part of the subscriber of RxJava as shown.

```
    fun requestAutocomplete() {
        mApi.add().subscribeOn(
            Schedulers.io()
          ).observeOn(
            AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
          ).subscribe({
            it?.let {
              //do something
            }
          }, {
            try {
             //do something
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
              view.doThis(ex)
            }
          })
        )
      }
```

I want to cover the catch block to increase my code coverage. I can not remove it from actual code which was written a long time back.

This is what I tried but with no success:

```
    @Test fun handleExceptionRequestAutoComplete() {
        Mockito.doAnswer({throwException()}).`when`(
            mApi.add()
          )
        )
        presenter.requestAutocomplete()
        Mockito.verify(view).doThis(throwException())
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test code is making the original code throw an exception when `mApi.add()` is called.

What you want is to emit an error when the result of `mApi.add()` is subscribed to.

Your test code should be:

```
    val exception = Throwable()
    val observableError = Observable.error(exception)
    Mockito.doReturn(observableError).`when`(
        mApi.add()
      )
    )

    val testObserver = mApi.add().test()

    testObserver
        .assertNotComplete()
        .assertError(exception)
```